# Radiator overflow, temperature increase, and radiator contains oily fluid

Tags: dodge, radiator, battery-charger

I have Dodge Charger 2007 model, ran 145000kms. Suddenly I found temperature of radiator comes high and starts overflowing radiator fluid, which is mixed with oil. Car is in running condition, but if we start the engine after 5 mins, the temperature rises again. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 5):

Most likely problem is a stuck thermostat and a blown headgasket.

Comment: Yep as soon as I saw "radiator contains oily fluid", I also thought blown headgasket.

Answer (score 0):

Oil and/or combustion residue in your coolant signifies a blown headgasket. Coupled with the overheating it sounds like your cooling system can't get up to pressure, again signifying a blown gasket.

Answer (score 0):

If you've ran it beyond or at the red mark, headgasket. If you noticed it before this happened Rear Main Seal, which is still expensive in a way as you need to take out the transmission but better then a headgasket.